# Jupyter lab incorrectly uses base python executable, jupyter notebook correctly uses venv executable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I created a new virtual environment:

```
conda create -n ml python=3.7 jupyter
activate ml
```

then, from command line I run jupyter **lab**

```
> jupyter lab
```

and from the prompt in a notebook in jupyter lab:

```
In  [1]: import sys
In  [2]: sys.executable
Out [2]: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'
In  [3]: !where jupyter
Out [3]: C:\Users\ragingroosevelt\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml\Scripts\jupyter.exe
```

Next, I start jupyter **notebook** (from the same command prompt window)

```
> jupyter notebook
```

and from the prompt in a notebook:

```
In  [1]: import sys
In  [2]: sys.executable
Out [2]: 'C:\\Users\\ragingroosevelt\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\ml\\python.exe'
In  [3]: !where jupyter
Out [3]: C:\Users\ragingroosevelt\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml\Scripts\jupyter.exe
```

I'm not sure what's causing the issue.  I assume there's something in notebook startup scripts that lab is missing that take the virtual environment into account?

What is causing this issue?  How would I got about fixing it?

Comment: It appears that you changed conda environment to the new one only after installing jupyter in the default / previous environment. This might be just a typo in the question though.

Comment: @krassowski thanks! fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept poking around.  It appears that jupyter lab is actually an python library (`jupyterlab`) independent of jupyter and because I hadn't installed it in my `ml` virtual environment, it was using the `jupyterlab` install of the anaconda base virtual environment.  I hadn't heard of this type of bleed-over before but that seems to be the cause of the problem.

```
> conda install --name ml jupyterlab
```

resolved the issue.